# PostgreSQL conditional expressions

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

Is there a way to write two insert statements if a javascript object's value is not an empty string, or one insert statement if it is an empty string in a postgreSQL query using `node-postgres`?

My database table "job" setup:

```
CREATE TABLE "job" (
  "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "company" VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL
);
```

For example, I would like this object to insert two rows:

```
{
  company: 'Apple',
  company_two: 'Google'
}
```

And I would like this object to insert one row:

```
{
  company: 'Facebook',
  company_two: ''
}
```

If the javascript object has a value for "company_two", I would like to add a second row to the database.

Here is what I have working to insert one row, but this doesn't take the other property into account:

```
pool.query('INSERT INTO "job" ("company") VALUES $1', [testObject.company]);
```

Comment: Why not simply checking `company_two` and if it has a value issue a second query?

Comment: Or look at the object and use `pool.query('INSERT INTO "job" ("company") VALUES ($1), ($2)', [testObject.company, testObject.company_two])` if it has both keys?

Comment: @Giovanni I would like to do it all in a single query so if the query fails, the entire transaction fails.

Comment: @ mu I'm looking for inserting two separate rows, not a second column.  This is a requirement for my specific project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "unnest" the JSON to rows, and then use that as the source for an insert:

```
insert into job (company)
select t.comp
from jsonb_each_text('{
              "company": "Apple",
              "company_two": "Google"
              }'::jsonb) t(k,comp)
where t.comp <> '';
```

will insert both companies.

And this will only insert one row:

```
insert into job (company)
select t.comp
from jsonb_each_text('{
              "company": "Facebook",
              "company_two": ""
              }'::jsonb) t(k,comp)
where t.comp <> '';
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the object has a value in the `company_two` property and act accordingly, for example:

```
const query = 'INSERT INTO "job" ("company") VALUES ($1)';

if (testObject.company_two != '') {
  pool.query(`${query}, ($2)`, [ testObject.company, textObject.company_two ]);
} else {
  pool.query(query, [ testObject.company ]);
}
```

This will insert a single row if `company_two` is an empty string and two rows if it is not and empty string. Of course you should adjust the `if` condition to match what you expect.